# plug in .net 4.0 into .net 2.0 testing

Tags: .net, windows, testing, plugins, com

I have a plug in developed with .net 4.0, using WPF. I now have to plug this into to my customers app which is running .net 2.0. I believe I can do this using COM.

Is there another way to plug this in without using COM, as I believe to do this the customer would have to modify their plug in architecture.

But how can I test this on my system, which is Windows 7 with .net 4.0?

Would i need to uninstall 4.0 and install 2.0? But then I couldn't develop more 4.0 features for the plug in.

Should I get a separate system, maybe running Windows XP?

Or maybe an emulator? or a VM?

What would u recommend please ?

Comment: Why can't you just use your .NET 4.0 plugin in the 2.0 application? This works if .NET 4 is installed - obviously - and if you declare an app.config like this: `<configuration><startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" /></startup></configuration>`

Answer (score 1):

That is an interesting problem you face; and I have been in that very same situation before.  As was mentioned in the comment above, I *highly* recommend that you use a VM to test.  In point of fact, there is a great write-up on the 'how-to' of it [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/megand/archive/2005/01/18/355668.aspx) and [here](http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/use-vmware-player).  There are also some great tools [here](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools).

I hope this helps!